# Ошибка при установке sass

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

Добавил sass все работает нормально, когда пытаюсь установить проект повторно, делаю команду npm install , выходят ошибки

```
npm WARN sass-loader@10.0.3 requires a peer of webpack@^4.36.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@10.0.3 requires a peer of node-sass@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@10.0.3 requires a peer of fibers@>= 3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Comment: npm WARN - предупреждения

Answer (score 0):

в package.json должны быть зависимости соответствующих версий (webpack 4 или 5, node-sass 4 и fibers не ниже 3.1.0